# Undeclared variable error during gcc 4.9.1 compilation

Tags: gcc, g++

I've an OpenSUSE OS and want to compile GCC from scratch. I want to compile 4.9.1 version because of the c++11 support. I am following this guide [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/InstallingGCC). I am using gcc version 4.8.3 for compilation. After executing make, I get following errors;

```
libtool: compile:  /mnt/disk2/gccWork-Ozgur/4.9.1-objdir/./gcc/xgcc -shared-libgcc -B/mnt/disk2/gccWork-Ozgur/4.9.1-objdir/./gcc -nostdinc++ -L/mnt/disk2/gccWork-Ozgur/4.9.1-objdir/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/src -L/mnt/disk2/gccWork-Ozgur/4.9.1-objdir/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/src/.libs -L/mnt/disk2/gccWork-Ozgur/4.9.1-objdir/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/.libs -B/mnt/disk2/gccWork-Ozgur/4.9.1-install/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ -B/mnt/disk2/gccWork-Ozgur/4.9.1-install/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/ -isystem /mnt/disk2/gccWork-Ozgur/4.9.1-install/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include -isystem /mnt/disk2/gccWork-Ozgur/4.9.1-install/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/sys-include -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_DEBUG -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS -I. -I../../../../gcc-4.9.1/libsanitizer/sanitizer_common -I.. -I ../../../../gcc-4.9.1/libsanitizer/include -isystem ../../../../gcc-4.9.1/libsanitizer/include/system -Wall -W -Wno-unused-parameter -Wwrite-strings -pedantic -Wno-long-long -fPIC -fno-builtin -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fomit-frame-pointer -funwind-tables -fvisibility=hidden -Wno-variadic-macros -I../../libstdc++-v3/include -I../../libstdc++-v3/include/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu -I../../../../gcc-4.9.1/libsanitizer/../libstdc++-v3/libsupc++ -DSANITIZER_LIBBACKTRACE -DSANITIZER_CP_DEMANGLE -I ../../../../gcc-4.9.1/libsanitizer/../libbacktrace -I ../libbacktrace -I ../../../../gcc-4.9.1/libsanitizer/../include -include ../../../../gcc-4.9.1/libsanitizer/libbacktrace/backtrace-rename.h -g -O2 -D_GNU_SOURCE -MT sanitizer_platform_limits_posix.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/sanitizer_platform_limits_posix.Tpo -c ../../../../gcc-4.9.1/libsanitizer/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_platform_limits_posix.cc  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/sanitizer_platform_limits_posix.o
../../../../gcc-4.9.1/libsanitizer/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_platform_limits_posix.cc:232:27: error: â€˜PTRACE_GETSIGINFOâ€™ was not declared in this scope
   int ptrace_getsiginfo = PTRACE_GETSIGINFO;
                           ^
../../../../gcc-4.9.1/libsanitizer/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_platform_limits_posix.cc:233:27: error: â€˜PTRACE_SETSIGINFOâ€™ was not declared in this scope
   int ptrace_setsiginfo = PTRACE_SETSIGINFO;
                           ^
../../../../gcc-4.9.1/libsanitizer/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_platform_limits_posix.cc:390:30: error: â€˜EVIOCGREPâ€™ was not declared in this scope
   unsigned IOCTL_EVIOCGREP = EVIOCGREP;
                              ^
../../../../gcc-4.9.1/libsanitizer/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_platform_limits_posix.cc:399:30: error: â€˜EVIOCSREPâ€™ was not declared in this scope
   unsigned IOCTL_EVIOCSREP = EVIOCSREP;
                              ^
../../../../gcc-4.9.1/libsanitizer/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_platform_limits_posix.cc:682:36: error: â€˜FS_IOC_GETFLAGSâ€™ was not declared in this scope
   unsigned IOCTL_FS_IOC_GETFLAGS = FS_IOC_GETFLAGS;
                                    ^
../../../../gcc-4.9.1/libsanitizer/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_platform_limits_posix.cc:683:38: error: â€˜FS_IOC_GETVERSIONâ€™ was not declared in this scope
   unsigned IOCTL_FS_IOC_GETVERSION = FS_IOC_GETVERSION;
                                      ^
../../../../gcc-4.9.1/libsanitizer/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_platform_limits_posix.cc:684:36: error: â€˜FS_IOC_SETFLAGSâ€™ was not declared in this scope
   unsigned IOCTL_FS_IOC_SETFLAGS = FS_IOC_SETFLAGS;
                                    ^
../../../../gcc-4.9.1/libsanitizer/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_platform_limits_posix.cc:685:38: error: â€˜FS_IOC_SETVERSIONâ€™ was not declared in this scope
   unsigned IOCTL_FS_IOC_SETVERSION = FS_IOC_SETVERSION;
                                      ^
make[4]: *** [sanitizer_platform_limits_posix.lo] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory `/mnt/disk2/gccWork-Ozgur/4.9.1-objdir/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libsanitizer/sanitizer_common'
make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/mnt/disk2/gccWork-Ozgur/4.9.1-objdir/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libsanitizer'
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/mnt/disk2/gccWork-Ozgur/4.9.1-objdir/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libsanitizer'
make[1]: *** [all-target-libsanitizer] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/mnt/disk2/gccWork-Ozgur/4.9.1-objdir'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you